# how can I bulk index a json file into elasticsearch?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, curl, elasticsearch

I am doing the works of "Shakespeare tutorial" for elasticsearch. The elasticsearch instance is set up on AWS, like so:

```
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 40,
    "successful" : 20,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_all" : {
    "primaries" : { },
    "total" : { }
  },
  "indices" : {
    "rentalyield" : {
      "primaries" : { },
      "total" : { }
    },
    "yield" : {
      "primaries" : { },
      "total" : { }
    },
    "r" : {
      "primaries" : { },
      "total" : { }
    },
    "shakespeare" : {
      "primaries" : { },
      "total" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

I have created a map as follows:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/shakespeare -d '
{
 "mappings" : {
  "_default_" : {
   "properties" : {
    "speaker" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
    "play_name" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
    "line_id" : { "type" : "integer" },
    "speech_number" : { "type" : "integer" }
   }
  }
 }
}
';
```

The shakespeare.json file is on my local machine and also on S3 on AWS, so I have tried:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @shakespeare.json
```

which fails with this error message:

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "shakespeare.json", this makes an empty
Warning: POST.
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"},"status":400}
```

and I have also tried:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/shakespeare/type/_bulk?pretty=true --data-binary @https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/richjson/shakespeare.json
```

which produces the same error.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: {"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"act","_id":0}}
{"line_id":1,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":"","line_number":"","speaker":"","text_entry":"ACT I"}

Comment: it should be OK because the json document was produced by elasticsearch fro the purposes of their tutorial

Comment: Yes I saw, try to add \n in the last line.

Comment: right at the end of the (HUGE) document or after every line?

Comment: At the final of the document, the last action must end with \n as described in [bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

Comment: I placed \n once right at the end of the document and then tried  curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @shakespeare.json whcih produced the same error.